# SSRS reporting service firevent thowing exception

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

`rs.fireevent()` is throwing permission issue

> The permissions granted to user 'xcx\sdfs' are insufficient for
> performing this operation. --->
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException:
> The permissions granted to user 'dfgfd\dsfsd' are insufficient for
> performing this operation. with this event
> rs.FireEvent("TimedSubscription",
> "bded0ae1-qwwew-4f4b-92dc-141046f3bebc", null);

Even though I have admin rights.
Any solution for this?